# How to apply a lambda function to certain rows in a data frame in pandas and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:
`df1`:

```
nameID  value1  Value2  Value3
name1   10      20      30
name2   15      25      35
name3   7       8       9
name4   5       6       7
```

I want to create a new column `result` such that if `nameID` is in `['name1,'name3]` then `result = value1 * value2`. Otherwise, `result = value1* value3`. I would like to use lambda functions.

```
nameID  value1  Value2  Value3  result
name1   10      20      30      200
name2   15      25      35      525
name3   7       8       9       56
name4   5       6       7       35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `np.where`

```
np.where(df['nameID'].isin(['name1','name3']),df1.value1*df1.Value2 ,df1.value1*df1.Value3)
Out[182]: array([200, 525,  56,  35], dtype=int64)

#df1['result'] = np.where(df['nameID'].isin(['name1','name3']),df1.value1*df1.Value2 ,df1.value1*df1.Value3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use `np.where` (@Wen`s answer).

Just to answer your question, a lambda func would take this format:

```
df.apply(lambda k: k['value1']*k['value2'] if k['nameID'] in (['name1', 'name3']) else k['value1']*k['value3'], axis=1)

0    200
1    525
2     56
3     35
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a new result column in the Dataframe

```
df['result'] = np.where(df.nameID.isin(['name1','name3']), df['value1'] * df['value2'], df['value1'] * df['value3'])
```

Output:

```
Result
200
525
56
35
```